# Is there more idiomatic ruby to perform this iteration?

Tags: ruby, refactoring, iteration

I am iterating through a set of ids and want to return the first object which returns `true` when a predicate method is called on it. A few lines of code is worth a thousand words:

```
def applicable_question(question_ids)
  ordered_ids(question_ids, order).detect do |question_id|
    question = Question.find_by(id: question_id)
    return question if question.applicable_for?(self)
  end
end
```

Stripping away the domain terms:

```
def desired_thing(ids)
  ids.detect do |id|
    thing = Thing.new(id)
    return thing if thing.true?
  end
end
```

Is there a more idiomatic approach here? Specifically, I feel like I am abusing `detect`. I immediately reached for `each` and `break`, but didn't get very far with that approach.

A requirement for this code is for it to not need to instantiate a large array of objects (ActiveRecord subtypes for example) to find the desired thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
desired_thing = ids.detect do |id|
  thing = Thing.new(id)
  return thing if thing.true?
end
```

If `thing` is found for which `thing.true?` is `true`, `detect` never returns an element of `ids` (to be assigned to `desired_thing`) because it's preempted by `return`. On the other hand, if the block completes without `return` being invoked, `detect` returns `nil` and assigns that value to `desired_thing`, but that `nil` value is of no use in the code that follows. It therefore would be better to just write:

```
ids.each do |id|
  thing = Thing.new(id)
  return thing if thing.true?
end
```

Comment: I don't want to find the first non-`nil` thing - I want to find the first thing that meets the predicate condition.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help - this definitely got me close to the solution that eventually worked.

> but that nil value is of no use in the code that follows.
The code snippet in the original (since edited) question statement didn't show that the lines of code in question were actually in a method. As such, the `nil` return value is significant.

Implementing your solution and then returning `nil` in the last line of the method worked like a charm. Slightly more verbose, but definitely clearer code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are almost there.

From the `find_by_id` method, I assume that `Question` is a class with some kind of `ActiveRecord` functionality, so I would expect a `where` method to exist as well.

In that case:

```
applicable_question = Question.where(id: ids).order(...).detect do |question|
  question.applicable_for?(self)
end
```

will do just fine.

It doesn't feel like abusing `detect`, you just need to have the correct enumerable set of objects.

#### Update

If instantiating too many objects is not an acceptable solution, then https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176622/687142 is the way to go. Keep in mind that both approaches have their drawbacks.

- `Question.where(id: ids).order(...).detect {|q| q.condition? }` will do a single query to the database but instantiate too many objects.
- `ids.each {|id| q = Question.find(id); return q if q.condition? }` will perform too many queries to the database but only instantiate one object at a time

The first approach is constantly heavy (memory wise) while the second one's performance depends on the order that you retrieve the records and can become quite expensive as well.

The best choice depends on your data set as well. If you have hundreds of thousands of questions the first approach is out of the question.

Maybe the best choice is to try to order the records in a way that `condition?` is more likely to be true

Comment: One of the goals of this method is to avoid instantiating all the question records being considered. Is `detect` overriden on `ActiveRecord::Relation`? If not, won't the `.where.order` chain get converted to an `array`, hence evaluating a lot of unnecessary SQL and instantiating a lot of objects?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @dleve123 Yes it will evaluate the records. Maybe you should update the question to include that constraint as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you have isn't far off from what you're trying to do. I would do something like:

`desired_thing = ids.detect{ |id| Thing.new(id) }`

I'm not sure if you're trying to stay away from SQL methods like find_by_id or where, but I'm sure you could use those too unless you NEED to use detect (or find).